# ASP.NET Core Google Sign In Returns 403

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, asp.net-core, google-signin

I know I am missing something obvious, but I cannot figure out what it is.  I'm trying to make a simple 'Login with Google' test app, and after I get the google consent screen, it follows with a 403 on my site.

In Startup, I configure cookie and google:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Login"),
    AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Denied")
});

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
    SignInScheme = "Cookies",
    ClientId = "xxx"                                                                      
    ClientSecret = "xxx"                                                                 
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

I've configured the google api to hit the endpoint the middleware creates:

[image]

but the callback from google to `http://localhost:5000/signin-google?state=xxxxxxx` gives me a 403 error.  My developer exceptions page shows:

[image]

My login method is simply:

```
[HttpGet("login")]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
   return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
   {
       RedirectUri = returnUrl ??  "Home/Index"
   });
}
```

Can someone help me with my flawed understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Gah.  I got it.  Turns out my app was configured correctly. I had to 'Enable' the Google+ API in google's console API:

[image]

If someone knows the reasoning behind this, or why it's not very obvious that you need to do this, I'd certainly like to know.